# Is it okay creating another branch from feature branch when using Git-flow?

Tags: git

1. I completed making functions in `feature1` branch and asked to merge with `develop` branch.
2. I have no permission to merge `feature1` branch to `develop` branch.
3. Merging `feature1` branch to `develop` branch is slow due to code review and some situation, but I want to make `feature2` branch which needs `feature1` branch's functions.
4. I decided to make `feature2` branch which derived from `feature1` branch **despite the chance of big change after code review.**
5. I will ask merging `feature2` branch to `develop` branch when `feature1` branch is completly merged to `develop` branch
6. The one who has a merging permission uses rebase when merging is completed.

Is there are any exception excluding NO.4 or any solutions for NO.3?

Comment: It looks like git-flow is not helping at all.

Answer (score 2):

This flow is completely valid and being used many times.

How ever - there could be a catch here:

If you merge `feature1` branch to `develop` branch and squash your changes, then the original commits are replaced with one single commit.

So when you go back to `feature2` and want to rebase your self on top of `develop` you may have conflicts.

The workaround for that, is to use interactive rebase, and don't select the commits on `feature2` that came from `feature1` and were already squashed.